# Is it possible to mirror emojis on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, emoji

I would like to use a mirrored emoji() in an imessage  - is that possible?
(I am interested in both mirrored, flipped and rotated emojis)

I have tried to use http://fliptext.net but is does not support emojis. I have tried to take a screenshot, and crop it to only the emoji(and rotate it), but for some reason it also gets stretched. What is the resolution of original emojis? -maybe a mirrored emoji can be prepared on a computer and transferred to the phone?

**Edit :** I would like the new emoji-picture to look just as nice as the original(resolution, antialiasing and size) - I have had no luck achieving this.

Comment: Does it need to be sent as text or can it be sent as an image? From a developers point of view, I can only see this if we crop and rotate the emojis and make a new keyboard for them. Don't think it is possible with integrated Emoji keyboard.

Comment: @emotality: I do not believe that the unicode mirrored chars exist, so a image is ok, and I do not even need a special keyboard for them(unless that is the only way).

Answer (score 3):

As mirrored emoji are not actual Unicode characters, the only way to accomplish this would be to edit an image with an emoji in Preview or another editing program. The directions provided are for preview.app on any mac.

1. Open Preview
2. Open any image that is just a plain transparent background, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1680&bih=837&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=blank+transparent+background+png&oq=blank+transparent+background+png&gs_l=img.3...3531.5194.0.5309.5.5.0.0.0.0.167.471.1j3.4.0....0...1.1.64.img..1.2.243...0j0i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1.KAiGkCSHndg#imgrc=2qqBwWGWG9MgLM:)
3. Open the markup [image: markup] toolbox
4. Add a new text box, and insert the emoji. You can type emoji using **Edit > Emoji & Symbols**, or the touchbar on a new MacBook Pro.
5. Now, click **Tools > Flip Horizontal**
6. Save your image. Now you've made a flipped emoji that you can place anywhere you want.

Here's your reversed megaphone, too: [image: flipped megaphone] [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJlPH.png)